# How to fire event only after press enter or changing selected item in JcomboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` that is editable. I need to fire event only following situations

1. user press enter while typing (this can be achieved adding key event listener) OR
2. user select item from list

in the following code, `event fires while user typing in the editor as well`,How can i avoid event firing while user typing?

```
comboForward.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
               new Thread() {
                    @Override
                   public void run() {
                      // code after the event.
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If user select an Item from the list and didn't press enter, what should happen..? Will the event run..?

Comment: in that case i need to fire an event. All i want is `NOT` to fire event while user typing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is suitable for you. try it.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome!!");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JComboBox cmb = new JComboBox();
cmb.setEditable(true);
cmb.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (((JTextComponent) ((JComboBox) ((Component) event
                    .getSource()).getParent()).getEditor()
                    .getEditorComponent()).getText().isEmpty())
                System.out.println("please dont make me blank");
        }
    }
});
frame.add(cmb);

frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setSize(300, 50);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

refer here :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: But then I can't detect event that is fire after user select item from drop down.

Comment: combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected index=" + combo.getSelectedIndex()
            + " Selected item=" + combo.getSelectedItem());
      }
    });

Comment: this code when you select something on combobox, you get the selected item. try it.

Comment: in that case event fires while user typing, that is the thing that i don't want to happen

Comment: posted answer is for key released event. not typing.